# Free abelian subgroup of index 2.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups

Let $G$ be a group with the following presentation $G=gp(x,y \mid x^2=y^2=1)$. I need to know, what further information about $G$ can be derived from knowing that $G$ has a free abelian subgroup of index 2.

Comment: @BabakS. This group is not infinite dihedral. You would need $x^2=y^2=1$ for that to be so.

Comment: @user1729: Yes you're right. I missed there's not a 1, however; it is infinite. :-)

Comment: @BabakS. Indeed, it is a free product with amalgamation $\mathbb{Z}\ast_{2\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}$...(actually, re-reading the question, I wonder if the infinite dihedral group was what they were after?)

Comment: (@BabakS. Actually, this group has a subgroup of index two isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. This is the subgroup normally generated by $xy^{-1}$. So perhaps they weren't after $D_{\infty}$ after all...)

Comment: @user1729 @ BabakS. Yes, we are dealing with the infinite dihedral group. Sorry, for incorrectness. Edited it.

Comment: @R2D2 You really need to make your question more clear. It is unanswerable in its current form. I mean, what do you want to know?! (Actually, there is a rather neat classification of virtually-$\mathbb{Z}$ groups, which says (I my memory serves me well) that every virtually-$\mathbb{Z}$ group either has infinite centre or maps onto $D_{\infty}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No further information, as this group, as noted in the comments, is (isomorphic to) the infinite dihedral group, and thus has a free abelian subgroup $F$ of rank one (isomorphic to the integers, that is) and index $2$, and thus nornal.

This is $\langle x y \rangle$, as $(x y)^x = (x y)^y = y x = (x y)^{-1}$.

Comment: This is a non-answer - how can you say "no further information (can be derived)"? I mean, there are many, many things which we can deduce. Simply saying "we know what the group is" is pointless and meaningless! (Although, of course, the question is currently un-answerable, but then why answer it?!)